# Is it possible to write an integer to a file without converting it to a string?

Tags: python, math, square-root

I am trying to compute the square root of 2 (up to nearly 10 million digits) with the following code

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/username/Desktop')


def sqroot(a, digits):
    a = a * (10**(2*digits))
    x_prev = 0
    x_next = 1 * (10**digits)
    while x_prev != x_next:
        x_prev = x_next
        x_next = (x_prev + (a // x_prev)) >> 1
    return x_next

sqrt2 = sqroot(2,10000000) 

file = open("Root_2",'w')
file.write(sqrt2)
file.close()
```

The problem is, I cannot write it to a file as an integer (`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int`). I tried to convert it to a string but got an OverflowError as it is too big to convert to a string. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: `struct.pack` can convert finite numbers to bytes, as can various `numpy` approaches. But arbitrary-precision numbers is tricky ... you should probably be using `gmpy2` in this case, at least.

Comment: Is function `sqroot` suppose to return the square root of a number ?  If so, why does `sqrt(4, 2)` return `200`?  Also, what is n in your example (i.e. your result is in sqrt2)?

Comment: @DarrylG the OP uses an integer to represent the square root. The decimal point is implied (divide by 10**digits)

Comment: Did you mean `file.write(sqrt2)` in your code?

Comment: have you tried pickle or marshal? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html

Comment: After at least 15 minutes of execution, your `sqroot()` has still not returned. Please post a [mre] that others can test with.

Comment: @martineau unfortunately, lesser numbers do not provide such an error, and 10 million digits take a really long time to compute. I am not sure what to do here

Comment: "but got an OverflowError as it is too big to convert to a string" <- Can you please explain exactly how you did that conversion, and show the error message? This sounds implausible: a 10000000-digit integer is _not_ too large to convert to a string. It'll take some time to do that conversion for sure, but you definitely shouldn't be getting `OverflowError`. What version of Python is this?

Comment: BTW, is there any reason you're rolling your own integer square root rather than using either `math.isqrt` or `Decimal.sqrt`?

Comment: FWIW, on macOS 12.4 / Intel and Python 3.10.5, executing `s = str(10**10_000_000)` takes around 20 minutes, but does eventually succeed. I can't think of any way that this would be raising `OverflowError`.

Comment: In the way I showed in my answer, there is no need to convert to string. Just opening the file and using the builtin print function can print it. To verify, try to open a file and `print(10**10000000, file=f)`.

Comment: I also can't see any reason for it to give `OverflowError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write to the file like the following:

```
n = 10**10000000

with open("Root_2",'w') as f:
    print(n, file=f)
```

It will run without errors. Change `n` to the `10000000` digits number you get from your function.

Comment: Already tried. Is there some problem with using the builtin print function to print an integer to a file ?

Comment: But of course the OP's code is not runnable as it is. Is that what you are talking about ?

Comment: I'm talking about posting answers that you're not sure fix the problem or not.

Comment: Isn't the problem about printing an integer to a file ? In this case, I believe my answer is ok. Are you aware of some problem with using the builtin print function to print an integer to a file ? If so, please, let me know

Comment: I am not aware of any issue with `print` although it is not needed here. All I can say at this point is that is what the OP *thinks* is the problem — because I have not be able to reproduce it running their code because the `sqroot()` function hasn't returned yet after many minutes of execution.

Comment: If the OP posts a question that induces me to think his problem is the one I answered, sounds fair to me to keep my answer until the OP confirms his problem. Especially given the fact that you are already helping him to realize what his problem is.

Comment: You could test your answer without running the OP's `sqroot()` function and thereby know whether it solves at least what they think their problem is or not.

Comment: This was the first thing I did. I opened an instance of the interactive python in my terminal and tryed to print an integer to a file like the OP is doing. It didn't work. But it worked when I tried with the builtin print function like I showed in my answer

Comment: In the OP's code, if the undefined `n` variable is an integer, the result is a `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int`, not an `OverflowError`. What I meant about testing your code was to have it write **10 million digits** to a file without using the `sqroot()` function which takes too long to execute (it's still running in the background on my computer).

Comment: I tested. Although it takes time, the builtin print function can print a number of 10000000 digits to a file in the way I put in my answer.

Comment: The code in your answer also references the undefined `n` variable, so it's obviously **not** the code you tested.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to put the exact code I tested